# Unsure of grep output because of bash wildcards

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to get a better understanding of bash commands.

```
ls /usr/include/ | grep \.h
```

It is supposed to list all the files ending in .h (C libraries) but it outputs more than expected.

**th**read_db **.h**

u**ch**ar **.h**

neta**sh**

If someone could also tell me how to bold the .h in the question without separating it from the rest of the name with a space, i would appriciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `grep`, your pattern is matching `.h` (any character followed by `h`) anywhere in the line, not just at the end.

You basically have two problems:

1. Quoting/escaping issue
2. Regex pattern issue

**Explanations:**

1. You have escaped `.` using `\.` and have not used any quotes or another `\`, so the escaping would escape the shell, and `grep` would get the Regex pattern as `.h`, in Regex term which means any character followed by a `h`. Your target is to make `grep` treat the `.` literal, so you need to quote or add another `\` like:

   ```
   '\.h'
   \\.h
   ```
2. Now the second problem, in regex, the end of a line is expressed by the quantifier `$`, so as you need to match the `.h` at the end of the line:

   ```
   '\.h$'
   ```

So, together the correct usage would be:

```
ls /usr/include/ | grep '\.h$'
```

---

Now the most important thing, Don't parse `ls`.

What you are doing can be easily and efficiently done by basic shell globbing:

```
ls /usr/include/*.h
```

Comment: Thanks, but i also wanted to know why it bolds sh, ch and th

Comment: `grep .*\.h` will as well work.

Comment: @someoneb100 check my edits..

Comment: @Videonauth No that would not. That would match e.g. `foo.hbar`